# Can we prove in general that gauge fields associated with broken generators form representations of the unbroken group?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, representation-theory, symmetry-breaking

The title is a bit ambiguous. More specifically, I'm asking:

Are all coupling between massive gauge fields (associated with broken generators) and massless gauge fields of the unbroken group are in the form of covariant derivatives of the massive gauge fields. (This covariant derivative is composed of massless gauge fields and the generators of the unbroken group)

Comment: In the renormalizable SM, the couplings of the photon to the $W^{\pm}, Z^0$ are minimal (via photon covariant derivatives); you are asking if there could be non-minimal coupling terms there?